# How to get value of attribute by name of ImageView object?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have 9 ImageView objects in a 3 x 3 grid layout which all call the same function when clicked. I need a way to know which of those from the grid was clicked when the function is called. 
One way to do this would be to use getTag() but I want the values "layout_row" and "layout_column" attributes. How can I do this ?

XML code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:rowCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="153dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red9"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red1"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red7"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red3"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red5"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red4"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red2"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red6"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/red8"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:onClick="dropIn"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0" />
```

I want something like: `val = view.getAttributeValue("app","layout_row")`

Answer (score 0):

I think that a GridView is the best choice for doing these things.
By the way if you want to do this, you can do `view.getId()` and compare it using a switch like this:

```
switch(view.getId()){
    case R.id.red1:
        ...
        break;
    case R.id.red2:
    ...
}
```